# Store a value in global scope after init hook is fired

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, hooks, init

I am working now on a Settings page. As I will need data about post types, taxonomies, and posts repeatedly in my setting page, I preferred to get these variables in the global scope and call them in the setting fields to minimize the database queries.

This was working well for built-in post types and taxonomies(i.e posts, pages, categories, and tags). However, neither custom post types nor custom taxonomies data can be retrieved as they are registered when the `init` hook fires. Here is my code snippet:

```
<?php
//I need to get these variables after init hook is fired to get all cpt and custom taxonomies data

$current_taxonomies_names = get_taxonomies($args, 'names');
$current_post_type_names = get_post_types($args, 'names');
$query_posts = get_posts($query_args);

//The above variables shall be used repeatedly in the below function

function appearance_settings()
{

  //Adding section and fields for the settings page
  add_settings_section('structure', 'App Structure', 'structure', 'main');
  add_settings_field('post_types', __('Post Types', ''), 'post_types', 'main', 'structure');
  add_settings_field('taxonomies', __('Taxonomies', ''), 'taxonomies', 'main', 'structure');
  add_settings_field('excluded_posts', __('Excluded Posts', ''), 'excluded_posts', 'main', 'structure');
  add_settings_field('excluded_taxes', __('Excluded Taxonomies', ''), 'excluded_taxes', 'main', 'structure');
}
```

So is there a way to get `$current_taxonomies_names`, `$current_post_type_names` or `$query_posts` after the `init` hook is fired?

If there is no way, is there any alternative to get these variables without keeping on querying the database in every setting field callback function?

Comment: Can you not move the `get_taxonomies` and `get_post_types` calls into those functions? You don't gain anything by making them shared/global variables

Comment: For sure I can. But I have many functions and I don't want to make excessive database queries for each setting field especially that these variables are nearly all site public data, there is also a call to `get_posts` as well. Anyway, I found that the best approach is to use a class and set all these variables after the init hook is fired in its `__construct()` function. This solved the issue.

Comment: neither `get_taxonomies` or `get_post_types` access the database

Comment: I checked and I found that you are right. For me, this is new information. Thank you. But anyway I still need the same for `get_posts`.

Comment: if you have a caching plugin or an object cache then it'll cache that on the same request too, the post objects at least will be cached so if there is a second query it will be much cheaper as it only needs to fetch the IDs

Answer (score 0):

So after consulting on Facebook Advanced WordPress group, the advice was to create an object with setters and getters instead of using the declaring and getting variables in the global scope as shown in the code below:

```
class MyPlugin
{
  public $current_post_types;

  public function __construct()
  {
    add_filter('init', array($this, 'get_variables'));
  }


  public function get_variables()
  {
    $this->current_post_types = get_post_types(array(
      'public' => true,
      'show_in_rest'   => true,
    ), 'objects');
  }
}

$skeleton = new MyPlugin();

function mk_post_types()
{
  global $skeleton;
  $current_post_types = $skeleton->current_post_types;
  //remaining code below
}
```

This solved the issue, now I can get all custom post types in the `mk_post_types` function.